# How can I find a list of Chrome's hidden URLs with chrome://?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Does Chrome publish a list of hidden URLs under the `chrome:` schema, such as, `chrome://memory-internals`? What else is available in that schema?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Complete List

Many of them seem to be undocumented and not listed in `chrome://chrome-urls` such as `chrome://interstitials/ssl`. You can find the **complete** list in the source code, under [`chrome/browser/ui/webui/chrome_url_data_manager_browsertest.cc`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/ui/webui/chrome_url_data_manager_browsertest.cc?q=media-engagement&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc). However, most of these are only enabled on some specific compilations of Chrome, such as Windows only, Linux only, or ChromeOS only specific builds.

Comment: The list in the mentioned source might not be complete since a source comment states "Non-exhaustive list of chrome:// URLs"

Answer (score 25):

You can also find clickable ones here: `chrome://chrome-urls`, whichever are available in your build. Not all seem to be there though.

There's also a separate `For Debug` category at the bottom which includes some URLs like `chrome://kill`. They can be found [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/common/chrome_debug_urls.cc?q=chrome:%2F%2Fkill&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc) in source code.

Comment: Are URLs like chrome://chrome-urls clickable if we don't put them in `code formatting`?  Nope, not by default, and even `[text](link)` doesn't work: [chrome://chrome-urls](chrome://chrome-urls).  Oh well.

Comment: @PeterCordes they get changed to `chrome//` without `:` for some reason.

Comment: Maybe it's a good thing that web pages can't send you to such pages since they can make browsers follow links without user interaction, especially via Javascript.